# populate feed even if no images in PHP

Tags: php

I need to populate an ecommerce feed with extraimages
here is the header :

```
|image_1|image_2|image_3|
```

I've a table where I store or not, extra images for one product.

So I make a request to see if there are some extra images, with an sql limit of 3 as I only want 3 images max in my feed.

What I need is to populate the feed with empty pipes if there are no images and I don't know the logic to do that.

The output would be, for example, like this if I have 2 extra images :

```
|url/image_1.jpg|url/image_2.jpg||   <- empty pipe to match the header of 3
```

or only one image :

```
|url/image_1.jpg|||
```

My code so far :

```
$products_extra_images_query = tep_db_query(
    "SELECT products_extra_image, products_extra_images_id 
    FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_EXTRA_IMAGES . 
    " WHERE products_id='" . (int)$row->id . "' LIMIT 3"); 

if (tep_db_num_rows($products_extra_images_query) >= 1){ 
    // there are some extra_images
    while ($extra_images = tep_db_fetch_array($products_extra_images_query)) {  
        $output .=  $extra_images['products_extra_image']."|" ; 
    }
}
```

thanks for your help.
Sebastien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of 4 and put your image path into it, then implode it into a string separated by "|".

```
$images = array_fill(0,4,null);
$idx = 0;
if (tep_db_num_rows($products_extra_images_query) >= 1) { 
    // there are some extra_images
    while ($extra_images = tep_db_fetch_array($products_extra_images_query)) {  
        $images[$idx] = $extra_images['products_extra_image'];
        $idx++; 
    }
}
$output .= implode($images, '|');
```

Comment: Firts try, First hit ! Well done and thanks for your help. I'm definitely not a coder !

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then you could try an approach like this ~ though using non-standard names such as `tep_db_fetch_array` perhaps confuse the issue?

```
$rows = tep_db_num_rows( $products_extra_images_query );
if ( $rows > 0 ){ 

    $output=[];

    /* add found records to the `output` array rather than a string - or, use `fetch_all` */
    while( $extra_images = tep_db_fetch_array($products_extra_images_query)) {  
        $output[]=$extra_images['products_extra_image']; 
    }

    /* an odd looking loop but should add extra `pipe` chars when there are not 3 results */
    for( $i=0; $i < ( 3 - $rows ); $i++ )$output[]='';
    echo '|' . implode('|',$output) . '|';

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! @bacteries answer worked for me.